# Mongoose $ne in Azure DocuemntDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I know that DocumentDB in Azure does not support everything that is supported for MongoDB (despite Ms general statement that it does). What I am trying to do is create an application that can switch between using MongoDB and DocumentDB. What I have found is that DocumentDB essentially ignores the `$ne` operator when passed in by Mongoose.

Thus when run against DocumentDB, the following line of code as the filter operator in a Mongoose .find query returns everything, regardless as to whether the record already contains the given rule._id or not.

```
WebsiteObj.SelectWebsite = function(rule, websiteUri, callback){
    Website.find(
        {websiteUri: websiteUri, 'rules': { '$ne': rule._id }},
        ['_id', 'websiteUri', 'ipAddress', 'createdAt'], function(err, websites){
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, rule, websites);
    });
};
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to resort to DocumentDB specific querying?

Comment: Please, give us some insight about your code

Comment: @israel.zinc added in the entire block of code that includes the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested `$ne` operator using Mongoose (`^4.9.2`) with DocuemntDB, it worked for me.

Here is my full code example,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://my-user-name:my-password@my-host:10250/test/?ssl=true');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!

  var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  });

  var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

  var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });

  fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    Kitten.find({name: { '$ne': 'fluffy' }}, function (err, kittens) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(kittens);
    })

  });

});
```

I get the empty array when I run the code.

Comment: Hmm,thanks Aaron, I will retest. I have since (unfortunately) decided to spin up a Linux VM after seeing expensive DocumentDB will quickly become with the collection based pricing. Off-topic for this question I know, but just to give a heads-up.

Comment: @Dave - as you said, off-topic, but... as you think about pricing, realize that you can easily store heterogeneous data in a single collection. Collection-per-object-type is typically unnecessary.

Comment: I get that but it's a fair backflip in the way of thinking/architecture for a database, SQL or NoSQL. Long term I understand multiple collections is a better architecture anyway. It's also an existing application that built on MongoDB that I thought I'd deploy to DocumentDB (loathe having to spin up/manage a VM). Not going to re-architect just to satisfy silly pricing model (suggestion: App Service Plan style "DocumentDB DB Service Plan" with collections). As a previous AWS zealot I now really, really like Azure but gee Ms have a habit of throwing a spanner in an almost awesome product!

Comment: For the record: I don't agree with "multiple collections is a better architecture" - *especially* with heterogeneous data. I don't see the value taking that approach in MongoDB either (aside from sharding) - and I've architected many-a-mongodb system.